# Percentage calculation returns zero

Tags: c++, math, floating-point, int, double

```
double calculatePercentage(int unmatched, int charLen){
    double percentageReturn = (((charLen - unmatched)/charLen) * 100);
    cout << "percenpercentageReturntage " << percentageReturn << endl;
    return percentageReturn;
}
```

I tried to calculate percentage of these values, but it returns `0`. I tried with `int`, `float` and `double` but all returns `0`.

Can anyone help me with this ?

Comment: Integer division truncates, and `(charLen - unmatched)/charLen` is an integer division.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the below statement, the right hand side of the assignment is evaluated first and then assigned to `percentageReturn` at which point the implicit conversion (if required) takes place.

```
double percentageReturn = (((charLen - unmatched)/charLen) * 100);
```

In the right hand side, all parameters are integers, so it will be integer division followed by the truncation of the result.

Since `(charLen - unmatched)` will be less than `charLen`, the truncated result will be 0.

To fix this, you can either cast the numerator or the denominator of the division to `double` and this will give you division without truncation.

`(double)(charLen - unmatched)` or `(double)charLen`.

Answer (score 2):

You may typecast `double` while doing division and multiplication operation so that as a whole result will be in `double`. You may do something like this:

```
double percentageReturn = ( ( (double)(charLen - unmatched) / (double)charLen ) * 100.0 );
```

Answer (score 1):

The division operator `/` in C++, performs an *integer division* when its both sides are of integral type. To overcome this, you need to cast arguments to a floating-point type first, as follows:

```
double cl = static_cast<double>(charLen);
double um = static_cast<double>(unmatched);
```

Note that if you're using Modern C++, it's a good practice to do cast the  implicitly convertible types with `static_cast`, instead of old C-style casts.

Answer (score 0):

To solve your issue please try one of this two possible solution

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
using namespace std;
double calculatePercentage(int unmatched, int charLen) {
    double percentageReturn = (((double)(charLen - unmatched) / (double)charLen) * 
100);
    cout << "percenpercentageReturntage_int " << percentageReturn << endl;

    return percentageReturn;
}
double calculatePercentage(double unmatched, double charLen) {
    double percentageReturn = (((charLen - unmatched) / charLen) * 100);
    cout << "percenpercentageReturntage_double " << percentageReturn << endl;
    return percentageReturn;
}

int main()
{

    cout << "the integer function  value is :" << calculatePercentage(4, 50) << endl;
    cout << "the double function  value is :" << calculatePercentage((double)4, 
(double)50) << endl;

    return 0;
}
```